# How to set Variables in Release pipeline in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: json, .net, powershell, azure-devops

I have searched all the documents about how to set variables to pass the variable during the run time build pipeline and only told me how to set in .yaml. But how to use it in release pipeline runtime variables?

Suppose I have a Generate-manifest.ps1 file which I will run to generate manifest.json file which representing the latest release packages with version number inside it. Version: 1.0.0. This version value should passed as a variable during runtime. I need help to do this.

[image]

Manifest.json file looks like this.:

```
{
"version":  "1.0.0",
"timeStamp":  "2021-05-07T09:41:34+00:00",
"packages":  [
                 {
                     "name":  "data-service",
                     "type":  "docker-image",
                     "version":  "REL-1.0.5367"
                 },
                 {
                     "name":  "feedback-service",
                     "type":  "docker-image",
                     "version":  "REL-1.0.6099"
                 },
             ]
 }
```

Comment: Release pipelines are now also YAML. Are you might be using the Pipelines / Releases area? As far as I can tell this is now legacy and you should use Pipleines/Pipelines to build you release pipelines

Comment: Actually I am using a repo in Azure DevOps which is having this "Generate-manifest.ps1" script, which needs to be run to generate manifest.json file with some version number. So I just want to pass that version number as a parameter for that pipeline.

Comment: You need to clarify: are you doing this in "Pipelines/Releases" (legacy, graphical) or "Pipelines/Pipelines" (YAML) I stronlgy recommend you move to YAML. As you can see, that is what all the doco supports now.

Comment: Ok sure, if I use YAML file to update the version in the manifest.json file, how to make it parameterised to pass it from the "Variables" section. Suppose once the manifest.json file is created , the "Variables" value should update the version value as 1.0.0 and create a file like manifest-1.0.0.json file

Comment: I expect you've already read all this, but YAML can capture variables from a variable group in a Library using `variables` keyword https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml You can also manually enter a variable value by pressing the Variables button in the YAML editor and adding it them using $(MyVariable) to refer to it in code. When you call your powershell with the `powershell` task, you can pass to variable in.

Comment: If you have YAML code you need to post it and point out the issue. If you don't have YAML code then we are speaking a different language here

Comment: Just to reiterate, the screenshot you have in your question is "releases". This is legacy and you shouldn't use it

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation I understand that you need to read version variable during the build pipeline and pass this variable on the release pipeline in order to use it on BuildNumber for example.

First you will need to use a powershell task to read the version value from the .json file.

```
$deployment_config = Get-Content manifest.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$versionNumber = $deployment_config.version
```

Then you can change the `BuildNumber` variable on build pipeline

```
$buildnumber = -join("v",$versionNumber ,"_","$(Build.BuildNumber)")
```

And also update

```
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$buildnumber"
```

You can then use the varialbe `$(Build.BuildNumber)` on release pipeline

[image: release pipeline]

Comment: Yes correct, but one glitch here is, I am not running any build pipeline. I am downloading some deploy scripts from artifactory in the Release pipeline and from those scripts itself I need to use of a manifest.json file which contains all version information on the latest packages. I can use this manifest for the next build but every time I trigger release pipeline the version should get update as a Release pipeline number with updating manifest.json file as "manifest-0.0.1.json" like this and store it in TFS itself.